# FreshAgent Get Asset Data

Tags: powershell, api

I am trying to fetch asset data from the Fresh client with Powershell. I am able to get any asset by typing it's name but I want to save some of the variables it returns so I can use it further.

```
$naam = Read-Host "Voer product naam in"
# Set global variables

$APIKey = 'Myapikey'
$EncodedCredentials = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $APIKey,$null)))
$HTTPHeaders = @{ "X-ApiKey" = $APIKey}
$HTTPHeaders.Add('Authorization', ("Basic {0}" -f $EncodedCredentials))
$HTTPHeaders.Add('Content-Type', 'application/json')


$URL = 'https://helpdesk.company.nl/cmdb/items/list.json?field=name&q='+$naam
(Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -Uri $URL -Headers $HTTPHeaders ).content
```

The following are some of the values that return after I run the above

```
{"config_items":[{"id":25000477949,"name":"SYS-MB1334","description":null,"ci_type_id":25000015988,"impact":1,"created_at":"2020-03-12T10:14:40+01:00","updated_at":"2020-04-24T16:42:42+02:00"
```

I would like to save the name and id variable for example

Comment: The json you show is invalid. Please update the question and show us more of the returned (sanitized) json data. You can check with [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the JSON you show is invalid.

Suppose the json returned from

```
$output = (Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -Uri $URL -Headers $HTTPHeaders ).Content
```

looks like:

```
{"config_items":
[{"id":25000477949,"name":"SYS-MB1334","description":null,"ci_type_id":25000015988,"impact":1,"created_at":"2020-03-12T10:14:40+01:00","updated_at":"2020-04-24T16:42:42+02:00"},
 {"id":12345678901,"name":"SYS-MB9876","description":null,"ci_type_id":12358745896,"impact":1,"created_at":"2020-03-12T10:14:40+01:00","updated_at":"2020-04-24T16:42:42+02:00"}]
}
```

Then you can collect the properties you need from the `config_items` using:

```
$result = ($output | ConvertFrom-Json).config_items | 
          Select-Object @{Name = 'Id';   Expression = {$_.id}},
                        @{Name = 'Name'; Expression = {$_.name}}

# output on screen
$result

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\TheOutput.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output on screen would look like

```
         Id Name      
         -- ----      
25000477949 SYS-MB1334
12345678901 SYS-MB9876
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I want to have the output on screen but I would like to have a variable which contains a value. for example if I would have a variable name:
$name
the output would be:
SYS-MB1334
and not the table like format it returns in the code above.

Comment: @CasvandenWijngaard Since you are retrieving an **array** of items, I would strongly recommend you do not try that. The values in the returned object array are all accessible by their property names like `$result[0].Id` and `$result[0].Name`

Comment: I am trying to fetch some more data from the code above but when I try to get the serial number it doesn't return anything. 
The following is the Config Item.
"serial_number_25000015139":"357960101864126"
When I try to get it with $result[0].serial_number_25000015139
it doesn't work. What is the correct way to do this because I don't get it.